# FileUpload.HasFile is always returning false

Tags: c#, ascx

`FileUpload.HasFile` is always returning false

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" style="width:240px;" /> 
     <br />
     <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
```

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "";

        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = filename;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                string str = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What file was uploaded? What was shown in `StatusLabel.Text `?

Comment: StatusLabel.Text equal " "

Comment: Well, I don't think that is possible (I assume you mean `""`) but let's put that to one side. Did you go into the `catch` block? That seems the simplest explanation. What was the **exact** value of `filename` (do **not** describe it - tell us the **exact** value)?

Comment: i can't read any value , if (FileUploadControl.HasFile) all time equal false

Comment: Did you go into the catch block? No
What was the exact value of filename (do not describe it - tell us the exact value)? it's image 

Comment: You are 100% sure a file is actually being uploaded? Did you check Developer Tools (Network tab) in Chrome?

Comment: yes i am sure and i am not checked dev. tools

Comment: Could not reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. Works for me.

Comment: Oh I've found it (probably). Do you specify `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` for your form? Don't do that. Don't specify anything. Let Asp.Net set it.